# htaccess : make directories exceptions from auto_prepend?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is there a way to make my auto_prepend command ignore my `includes/` and `ajax/` directories?

I can write regular expressions easily it's just knowing how to markup the conditional statements...

```
# choose which files are mother files (aka not includes or ajax)
# add dochead to these files
{some kind of regex conditioon here }
php_value auto_prepend_file  C:/wamp/www/new_glaven_valley/views/components/doc_head.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php_value auto_prepend_file none`

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use [LocationMathc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#locationmatch) or [directoryMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directorymatch) but my prefrence would be to use a stub file as the auto-prepend and select further includes based on the value of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in my php code - its a lot easier to describe complicated structures and relationships using a procedural language than a config file - and you don't need to reset your webserver every time you want to change / save the settings.

C.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stick .htaccess files in your includes/ and ajax/ directories that unset auto_prepend_file (or if that can't be done, you could always have those directories auto_prepend an empty file.

Comment: that sounds wicked, how do i unset an auto_prepend anyone please?
thanks!